# How to return an error in a Boolean method?

Tags: java, methods, return, boolean

I have a method that returns True or False depending on the input being either 'y' or 'n'. However I want it to return an error when anything else is entered to the question asked. I'm asking how to return a String for example in a Boolean Method. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean askYesNo(String question1) {
    question = question1;
    System.out.println(question);
    answer = kbdScanner.next();
    if (answer.charAt(0) == 'y') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (answer.charAt(0) == 'n') {
        return false;
    }
    return ?????;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read about exceptions; or you might want to use `Boolean` as the return type (so that you can return `null`, and then check for `null` in the calling code); or you might simply want to loop until you get `y` or `n` instead.

Comment: You can use [`Optional<Boolean>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). It lets you return `Optional.of(true)`, `Optional.of(false)` or `Optional.empty()`. This is similar to Andy's `Boolean` suggestion, but more explicit (and requires Java8).

Comment: you can throw a RuntimeException if you don't want the method to throw a checked exception

Comment: On an unrelated note, do you want "Y" and "N" to be valid? Or only "y" and "n"?

Comment: hmmmm, good point, I didn't think about that. I think id probably stick with 'y' and 'n'. Just to confirm tho, if I wanted 'Y' and 'N' as well id just have to add (... || answer.charAt(0) == 'Y' ...) no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution is to validate the answer before calling the method.
So in abstract code:

```
while (answer is not y or n) {
   ask question again
}
call method
```

Comment: Yes it works! But I used (answer.charAt(0) != 'y' && answer.charAt(0) != 'n') as condition for the while loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome. I know it is not exactlky the answer to the question you have asked (returning a string in a boolean method), but I guess this is what you want your program to do?

Comment: Yeah I want it to basically go, nope don't like that answer, try again.

Answer (score 1):

A method in Java can always only have one return type. In your case that is boolean, so you cannot return a String.

What you require is an Exception. Exceptions can be thrown e.g. if something unexpected happens. Read more about it here: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-exception-handling/

In your case, I suggest using an `IllegalArgumentException` since you want to handle the case that the method input is not valid.

Comment: Ok, I see. Its a lot shorter than the whole while loop creation, but it also terminates that method no?

Comment: Yes, throwing an exception terminates the method at that point. You will have to handle the exception where you call the method though. i.e. using a try-catch block. Explanation and details see [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do
`throw new IllegalArgumentException(question1);`